# App crash On Use Material Theme Android lollipop

Tags: android, material-design

I have used following code
colors file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="primary">#673AB7</color>
    <color name="primary_dark">#512DA8</color>
    <color name="accent">#E91E63</color>
    <color name="navigation_bar">#311B92</color>
    <color name="primary_text_color">#FFFFFF</color>
</resources>
```

style file

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

</style>


<style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
</style>
```

build.gradle file

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.demo.test"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0'
}
```

But app crash on my lolipop device

Error output is -:

```
24109-24109/com.example.test E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.test, PID: 24109
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.MainActivity}: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to color: type=0x1
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2534)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2614)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to color: type=0x1
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:404)
            at android.app.Activity.onApplyThemeResource(Activity.java:3738)
            at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.initializeTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:140)
            at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.setTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:85)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setTheme(AppCompatActivity.java:90)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2474)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2614)
```

MainActivity code is

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    }
}
```

and activity_main.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:padding="6sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The error seems to point to your color resources

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26958179/java-lang-unsupportedoperationexception-cant-convert-to-color-type-0x1

Comment: Thanks Eenvincible for comment. But what problem how can i fix it.

Comment: Unrelated also; padding is in dp, not sp; meanwhile, let me look at your code again!

Comment: Thanks Eenvincible. Problem have fixed according to your link.

Comment: Alright, so no need to add answer to this?