# Android app crashes on API equal or lower than 30

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-constraintlayout

My app crashes on API <=30 but it is working fine on API >30. Beneath I attach you my build.gradle file my .xml file and the error I get in console.

**Build.gradle file:**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'


    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.3")
    // define a BOM and its version
    implementation(platform("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-bom:4.9.3"))
    // define any required OkHttp artifacts without version
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp")
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor")

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

In console **I get the following error:**

```
/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 4230
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication/test.example.myapplication.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:706)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
        at test.example.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:50)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to ComplexColor: type=0x1
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadComplexColorForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:879)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadComplexColorFromName(ResourcesImpl.java:756)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadColorStateList(ResourcesImpl.java:835)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateList(Resources.java:998)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList(TypedArray.java:531)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4488)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:578)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:574)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:570)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.<init>(ConstraintLayout.java:587)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:706) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195) 
        at test.example.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:50) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756) 
Install successfully finished in 34 s 869 ms.
Failed to launch an application on all devices
```

I suspect that it maybe is a compatibility issue with Constraint Layout so I also attach you my
**.xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#8BC34A"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/material_dynamic_tertiary99"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <!-- Text View to display our basic heading of "calculator"-->

    <!-- Edit Text View to input 1st value -->

    <!-- Edit Text View to input 2nd value-->

    <!-- Text View to display result -->

    <!-- A button to perform 'sum' operation -->

    <!-- A button to perform subtraction operation. -->

    <!-- A button to perform division. -->

    <!-- A button to perform multiplication. -->

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/api3"
        android:layout_width="106dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="252dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/material_dynamic_neutral70"
        android:onClick="doGBP"
        android:text="@string/to_gbp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#283593"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/api2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/api2"
        android:layout_width="106dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="252dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/material_dynamic_neutral70"
        android:onClick="doAUD"
        android:text="@string/to_aud"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#283593"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/api3"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/api" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sum"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="57dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="376dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:onClick="doSum"
        android:text="+"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/sub"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sub"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="57dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="376dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/black"
        android:onClick="doSub"
        android:text="-"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/mul"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/sum"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/sum" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/mul"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="57dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="376dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/black"
        android:onClick="doMul"
        android:text="*"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/div"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/sub"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/sub" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/div"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="57dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="376dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/black"
        android:onClick="doDiv"
        android:text="/"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/mul"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/mul" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/api"
        android:layout_width="106dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="252dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/material_dynamic_neutral70"
        android:onClick="doUSD"
        android:text="to USD"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#283593"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/api2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Clear"
        android:layout_width="175dp"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="312dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/black"
        android:onClick="doClear"
        android:text="Clear All"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/num1"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.AutoCompleteTextView"
        android:layout_width="123dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="455dp"
        android:background="@color/material_dynamic_neutral90"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter \n number #1"
        android:inputType="number|text"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColorHint="#616161"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/num2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/num2"
        android:layout_width="123dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="455dp"
        android:background="@color/material_dynamic_neutral90"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter \n number #2"
        android:inputType="number|text"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColorHint="#616161"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/num1" />

    <!-- A button to Clear All Inputs simultaneously. -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="194dp"
        android:layout_height="43dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:scrollbarSize="30dp"
        android:text=" Calculator"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display4"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <!-- A button to manage the API -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/result"
        android:layout_width="298dp"
        android:layout_height="92dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="520dp"
        android:background="@color/material_dynamic_neutral90"
        android:hint="Result (Eur)"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
        android:textColorLink="#8254D3"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Update with the Main Activity Code I got requested at comment section**

[image: Code from Main Activity]

**Update #2 with colors.xml and themes.xml**
[image: colors.xml]
[image: themes.xml]

Comment: Did you change color using code in java/kotlin in MainActivity?

Comment: No, whatever color changes I have done in the interface I made them through Attributes in .xml design view

Comment: What's on line 50 in MainActivity?

Comment: I updated the original post with a screenshot of the code around line 50

Comment: Are your `colors.xml`, `themes.xml` or `styles.xml` API level dependent?

Comment: I don't have a styles.xml. I updated the post with colors.xml and themes.xml

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26958179/java-lang-unsupportedoperationexception-cant-convert-to-color-type-0x1

Comment: Before I made the post I tried to solve my problem through that post but I have not such error or code.

Answer (score 0):

Your XML is using Material colors introduced in API 31. That is why you are seeing crashes and why things work on API 31 but not on API 30 and below. You can do a simple test on this by executing

```
val color = resources.getColor(R.color.material_dynamic_tertiary99)
```

on APIs 30 and 31. On API 31, you will get the color value `0xfffffbfd`. On API 30, you will see a "resource not found" error. (This color is what you use for the background tint of your *ConstraintLayout*.)

That is the reason for the error. I am not familiar enough with the new Material system to give you a solution. It seems to me that there should be some back port, but I am not sure. You may need to do color resource versioning with *values-v31/colors.xml*.

Here are a few references that may help:

[Getting started with Material Components for Android](https://m3.material.io/libraries/mdc-android/getting-started)

[Using Material Colors in Your App](https://medium.com/@xch3dx/using-material-you-in-your-app-15ec982eecb4)