# after run the android xml file the app has install in my phone but the app is not opening

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I am totally new to android development and trying to learn it by my own, I have done some coding in xml file but when I run the application, app has install in my phone but not opening.

Here is the error log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.sumita.yourhelp, PID: 6407
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sumita.yourhelp/com.sumita.yourhelp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #39: Binary XML file line #39: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2994)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3072)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1766)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6977)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:528)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:910)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #39: Binary XML file line #39: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #39: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:650)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:797)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:737)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:870)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:831)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:710)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
        at com.sumita.yourhelp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7227)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7218)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2947)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3072)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1766)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6977)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:528)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:910)
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to ComplexColor: type=0x1
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadComplexColorForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:1217)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadComplexColorFromName(ResourcesImpl.java:1094)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadColorStateList(ResourcesImpl.java:1173)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateList(Resources.java:1076)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList(TypedArray.java:541)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:5180)
        at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:867)
        at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:166)
        at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:141)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:80)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:75)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:650) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:797) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:737) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:870) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:831) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:710) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195) 
        at com.sumita.yourhelp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7227) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7218) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2947) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3072) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1766) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6977) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:528) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:910)
```

And here is the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="11dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="258dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/About"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_contact_us" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Aboutus"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="?android:attr/colorFocusedHighlight"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="12"
        android:hint="enter number"
        android:inputType="number" />
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/material_dynamic_neutral40"
        android:text="contact us"
        android:textColor="@color/black"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please update your question to include the layout file you are using for your `MainActivity`. Your error log suggests the problem exists in this file. Also, see [this possibly related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26958179/java-lang-unsupportedoperationexception-cant-convert-to-color-type-0x1).

Comment: I have edit my question. please check it. I was just trying to learn simple frontend design.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Two relevant parts of your error log.

This section points to a problem in line 39 of your layout file, inflating an `AppCompatButton`.

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #39: Binary XML file line #39: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
```

There's also this in your error log:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to ComplexColor: type=0x1
```

So, taken together, your error log suggests that there's a problem with a color that's being used in an `AppCompatButton` on line 39 of your layout XML.

If you look at that line in your layout file, you'll see this:

```
android:textColor="@color/black"/>
```

Taken together, I would guess that you haven't defined the color you've called `black` correctly. Try and replace it with `@android:color/black` and see if that works. If it does, then you need to fix whatever color you've defined for `black` in your resources files.

Comment: Thank you it has worked, but may be that was not the problem I just copy paste everything in another project and then it works. Thank you so much for your help.